# Java динамическое добавление элементов

Tags: java

**Все спасибо, кто действительно хотел помочь, но я уже справился сам ;)
Не то делал, нужно было линейно все выстраивать, а не панелями.**

---

Приветствую! Уважаемые знатоки, пожалуйста помогите разобраться.
Мне нужно, чтобы на основной созданной панели - динамически добавлялись еще панели.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Test());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Окно
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        // Основная панель
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(p);
        p.setLayout(layout);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup hor = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING),
                vert = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false);
        SequentialGroup sgh = layout.createSequentialGroup(),
                sgv = layout.createSequentialGroup();

        // Панели которые добавлять на основную панель, где String это название, а int[] это ширина и высота
        final Map<String, int[]> parts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        parts.put("p1", new int[]{
            440,
            140
        });
        parts.put("p2", new int[]{
            120,
            200
        });
        parts.put("p3", new int[]{
            220,
            200
        });

        // Перебераем все панели которые добавляем
        for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> part : parts.entrySet()) {
            int[] pSize = part.getValue();
            JPanel pp = new JPanel();
            pp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pSize[0], pSize[1]));
            pp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(0, 0, 0)));

            sgh.addComponent(pp, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
            hor.addGroup(sgh);

            sgv.addComponent(pp, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
            vert.addGroup(sgv);

        }

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(hor);
        layout.setVerticalGroup(vert);

        frame.add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Получается фигня какая - то...
Дело в том, что мне нужно, чтобы панели добавлялись в основную не заходя за границы, чтобы если элемент не поместился, нужно уместить ниже.

Уже бьюсь какой день, никак не могу вникнуть, что я не так делаю...?(

Задача не из легких.
Спасайте кто чем сможет, если есть другой способ рисовать элементы разными размерами не выходя за границы и не наступая друг на друга, в допустимых местах, подскажите пожалуйста.

Пытался что - то найти, нигде нет, только одни слова, кода нет.
Хочу получить что - то вида раскройки, только для других целей, нужно чтобы программа запоминала каждый размещенный элемент на области

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было использовать Rectangle и Graphics.